# Override Model from third party vendor in custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme, model, di, class

I am trying to override a Model from a third Party vendor in a custom-theme. The original file was:

```
/vendor/3rdpartyompany/3rdpartymodule/Model/Formatter/BaseImage.php
```

I copied that file over to:

```
/vendor/customthemevendor/customtheme/Model/Formatter/BaseImage.php
```

and edited the namespace in that file:

```
namespace Customthemevendor\Customtheme\Model\Formatter;
```

Last I created a `/etc/di.xml` and set the preference:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="3rdPartyCompany\3rdPartyModule\Model\Formatter\BaseImage" type="Customthemevendor\Customtheme\Model\Formatter\BaseImage" />
</config>
```

Magento2 doesn't seem to recognize my customization at all. (Basically, there is a resize image function with hardcoded values in the function, that I need to change).

Is the Overriding-process the same for themes and modules or am I missing something?

Comment: You can override module in your custom module not in theme.

Comment: So, there is no way to overriding it in the theme?

Comment: No, you can only override layout, templates, css, js, web templates under theme.

Comment: thank you. If you like, you can post that as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only override layout, templates, css, js, web templates under theme.

So in order to override third party module model use plugin or preference in your **custom module**.

Thanks!